# How to merge output plots of 2 .slx files (simulink models)?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have created 2 different models for CPU scheduling algorithms. I am measuring average wait time. I want to plot the 2 outputs of average wait signal scope into one graph.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Saving output of both models in two different .mat files and then using these mat files as input to scope in third model will work.